# Adding a list from different starting point in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to sum a list with an index to specify the starting point. 
For example, `sum(1, List(1,2,3))` should return `2 + 3` as first parameter 1 specifies the starting value `List(1) == 2`. Likewise, `sum(2, List(1,2,3))` will return 3.

I have this code that does the functionality, but I think it's overly complicated. Are there simpler implementations?

```
def sum (index:Int, bits:List[Int]) = {
  ((bits zipWithIndex).filter { case (v, i) => i >= index}).unzip._1.sum
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
def sum(index: Int, bits: List[Int]) = bits.drop(index).sum
```